# How to change position of submenu?

Tags: css

I try to change position of submenu  in this menu. I  change position of instead  ul tag to relative But it don't worked correctly. When click on  the menu ,sub menu shown but  the main-menu to be scaled by the sub-menu.Please advice

```
<div id="cssmenu" style="direction:rtl;">
            <ul><li class="mobile"><a href="#"><span>Menu <i>☰</i></span></a></li>
    <li class="">
            <a href="http://localhost/dnn_test/"><span>صفحه نخست</span> </a>
        </li>
    <li class="has-sub active">
        <a href="http://localhost/dnn_test/skin2"><span>skin2</span> </a>
            <ul style="display: block;">
            <li class="">
            <a href="http://localhost/dnn_test/sub_skin2"><span>sub_skin2</span> </a>
        </li>
    <li class="">
            <a href="http://localhost/dnn_test/sub1_skin2"><span>sub1_skin2</span> </a>
        </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li class="has-sub">
            <a href="http://localhost/dnn_test/skin3"><span>skin3</span> </a>
            <ul style="display: none;">
            <li class="">
            <a href="http://localhost/dnn_test/sub1_skin3"><span>sub1_skin3</span> </a>
        </li>
        </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="">
            <a href="http://localhost/dnn_test/skin4"><span>skin4</span> </a>
        </li>
    <li class="">
            <a href="http://localhost/dnn_test/skin5"><span>skin5</span> </a>
        </li>
    <li class="">
            <a href="http://localhost/dnn_test/skin6"><span>skin6</span> </a>
        </li>
</ul>


<script>
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu > ul').prepend('<li class=\"mobile\"><a href=\"#\"><span>Menu <i>&#9776;</i></span></a></li>');
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function(e) {
  $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
  var checkElement = $(this).next();
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
    checkElement.slideUp('normal');
  }
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
  }
  if( $(this).parent().hasClass('mobile') ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#cssmenu').toggleClass('expand');
  }
  if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;   
  }     
});
});
} )( jQuery );
</script>
        </div>
```

CSS ____________________________________________________:

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300);
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Base Styles */
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu a {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background: #565656;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #565656), color-stop(100%, #323232));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#565656 0%, #323232 100%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #cssmenu > ul {
    max-height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
  #cssmenu.expand ul {
    max-height: 900px;
  }
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.mobile {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
  background: #444444;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444444 0%, #323232 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #444444), color-stop(100%, #323232));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444444 0%, #323232 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#444444 0%, #323232 100%);
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    border-right: 0 none;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.mobile i {
    float: right;
    font-style: normal;
  }
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child {
  border-right: 0 none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.mobile {
  border-right: 0 none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
}
/* Sub menu */
#cssmenu ul ul {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 5px 12px;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 33px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #cssmenu ul ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  padding: 3px 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: #444444;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a JsFiddle? And to rephrase your question: You don't want the main-menu to be scaled by the sub-menu below it, right?

Comment: Yes I don't want  the main-menu to be scaled by the sub-menu

Comment: You can see the demo on this adress : http://jsfiddle.net/hmahdavi921/ojdm4xre/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution/advice:

Change the position of the sub-menu to `absolute`, so it is taken out of the document-flow. Make sure that the parent `li` is set to `relative`:

```
#cssmenu ul ul {
  ....
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  ....
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ojdm4xre/2/

Comment: Sorry. Wrong jsFiddle link. Now it should be right!

Comment: puelo : In this case align of my menu is RTL and When run submenu should be hide and when click on the parent it should be shown . Can you provide this for RTL